# Fast 2d array numerical integration in Python

Tags: python, math, numerical-integration

(EDITED)

I need to perform numerical integration of:

[image: formula]

Where Pn - Legendre polynomial, λ – wavelength, ρ and z – matrices NxN size, J – zero kind Bessel function.

I wrote the following code:

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import datetime
from scipy.special import legendre, jn

image_size = 100
image_half_size = 50
scale = 10
cos_beta1 = 0.9999999
cos_beta2 = 0.01745
l_maxOrder = 10
wavelength = 660
k = 2 * np.pi / wavelength

x_center = 8 / scale
y_center = 14 / scale
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-image_half_size, image_half_size + 1) / scale,
                         np.arange(-image_half_size, image_half_size + 1) / scale,
                         sparse=False,
                         indexing='ij')

ro_p = np.sqrt((x-x_center)**2 + (y-y_center)**2 + 1e-4**2)

z = random.randint(-5, 5)
z_p = np.full((image_size + 1, image_size + 1), z)


def pi_plus_tau(n):
    def frst_deriv(arg):
        return  (n + 1) * (legendre(n+1)(arg) - arg*legendre(n)(arg)) / (arg**2-1)

    def sec_deriv(arg):
        return (n + 1) * (legendre(n)(arg)*((n-2)*(arg**4) + (3-n)*(arg**2)-1) / (arg**2-1) - legendre(n+1)(arg)*(5+2*n)*arg + legendre(n+2)(arg)*(n+2)) / (arg**2-1) ** 2

    def integrand(arg):
        coef = (-1 * jn(0, k * ro_p * (1-arg** 2) ** 0.5) * np.exp(1j * k * z_p * (1-arg)) * (arg**0.5))
        return (frst_deriv(arg) * (1 - arg) + (1 - arg ** 2) * sec_deriv(arg)) * coef

    return integrand


def intergration_plus(n, angle1, angle2):
    return (integrate.quad_vec(pi_plus_tau(int(n)), angle1, angle2, workers=1))[0]


for n in range(1, l_maxOrder):
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    intergration_plus(n, cos_beta1, cos_beta2)
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

This works well, but for N=100, the calculation takes approx. 10 seconds and I have to perform a series of calculations for different n-s. And do it many many times. So 10 seconds is too long.

This math expression is part of a bigger expression. When I run code listed above in this question - it runs twice as fast as when I run it inside the whole program.

Could You advise me - how to do fast numerical integration with 2d arrays in Python? Some packages, to use cython, any hints.

Thank You

Comment: In general, you should always try to vectorize your code, i.e., make sure it works for input arguments of arbitrary shpae. [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) does that, and it's perhaps a good reference. (Disclaimer: I wrote it.)

Comment: The `jn/jv` evaluation dominates the whole runtime. A parallelized cython version of your integrand looks to be the way to go. It would be very useful if you provide a runable example (this also includes some random inputs of the correct shape and datatype).

Answer (score 1):

The best that I could find to solve my problem is the quadpy library - https://pypi.org/project/quadpy/.
Group your data into an N-dimensional array e.g. (batch_size, Image_width, Image_height, Legendre order) and use np.multiply.outer.
Of all the options I tried, this provides the fastest calculation.